# Doorkeeper new_oauth_application_path not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, doorkeeper

I test the new rails 5 api. I want to create a oauth2 server consumme by a js client.

I use Doorkeeper to manage the oauth2 server.

In my routes.rb i have

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    use_doorkeeper
end
```

doorkeeper.rb

```
resource_owner_authenticator do
  User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) || redirect_to(new_user_session_url)
end
```

When i go to 'http://localhost:3000/oauth/applications', i got the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `new_oauth_application_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fbf1f70c908>:0x007fbf1f72f8b8>)
```

Is doorkeeper not fully functionnal with rails 5 ? If it's not, do you known some gem like Doorkeeper ?

I create manually the routes in routes.rb

examples:

```
  get '/oauth/applications/:id(.:format)', to: 'doorkeeper/applications#show', as: 'edit_oauth_application'
  get '/oauth/applications(.:format)', to: 'doorkeeper/applications#index', as: 'root'
```

And now i have "undefined method `flash'".

Comment: any luck with this? Same error here

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled across this same issue while trying to use doorkeeper on a Rails 5 api only application.

Changing my `ApplicationController` ancestor to `ActionController::Base`, as  suggested before did not work out for me. After digging a little deeper, I found a solution.

**Short answer is**: `doorkeeper` is not designed to work with api only apps, as you can see [here](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/issues/869) and [here](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/issues/821#issuecomment-212562425).

The way I managed to make it work, was to re-enable all the middleware and helpers that the `api-only` option for Rails 5 strips out...

In short, adding

```
require "sprockets/railtie"
```

at the top of `config/application.rb` and setting

```
config.api_only = false
```

in the same file, makes doorkeeper load as expected.

Even though now your application loads a bunch of Middleware previously stripped out, API functionality is maintained and controllers are still lightweight since they still inherit from `ActionController::API`.

Comment: My Rails application was not generating API tokens after updating Rails version to 5.2. Adding config.api_only = false in config/application.rb solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I change ActionController::API by ActionController::Base to make it work.